# move points in list such that entries are at least `dist` apart

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of reference floats, e.g.,

```py
x_ref = [-0.1, 1.0, 1.2, 3.5, 7.5, 12.0]
```

and I'd like to find a list of `x` such that two things are fulfilled:

- The entries in `x` are at least `dist` apart (e.g., 2.0)
- The entries in `x` are as close as possible to their `x_ref` partner, i.e., they minimizing the square distance

  ```py
  1/2 sum((x_ref[i] - x[i]) ** 2) -> min
  ```

I've cooked up something but it's quite bloated and probably buggy. Perhaps there's an easy way out here. Any hints?

Comment: It is hard to understand what it actually is you are after. How do you "move" a float? I recon that these floats might be x coordinates, but as I understand it all you need is `x_new = [x if x >= dist else dist for x in x_orig]` but that is probably wrong.

Comment: @beruic Thanks for the feedback. I've reworded the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify each critically congested area of your list, the largest subsequence (i, j) such that

```
(x[j] - x[i]) / 2.0 < j-i
```

**EDIT**
Nico's comment is spot on: I didn't allow for an effectively open interval on one end.  I *think* that adjusting the gap identification will do the trick ...

```
(x[j] - x[i]) / 2.0 < j-i-1
```

**EDIT END**

In your given example, there is only one such location, values -0.1 through 3.5, a difference of 3.6 where a spread of 6.0 is required.  The minimal spread will consist of numbers `p + 2.0 * k` for k in the closed interval [0, (j-i)]

You now have the expression for your error:

```
sum for k = 0, (j-i)
    (x[k] - (p + 2k))^2
```

All of the `x[k]` values are known, and all of the `2k` values are known.  Expand the expression, solve for `p`, and minimize -- take the derivative and set that to 0.  The resulting `p` value gives you the new value of `x[i]`, and the others follow from that.

Comment: There's something wrong with the block building. Consider `[0, 0, 3.5]`, with `dist = 2`. The solution is `[-1, 1, 3.5]` (I think), but the `3.5` is unnecessarily part of the block in your algorithm.

Comment: You're right -- I need to adapt that initial check with the open areas on each end.